# How does RPL calculate ETX among nodes without data packets (UDP/TCP) at the beginning?

Tags: routes, wireless, contiki

I am wondering how RPL calculates ETX link metric at the initialization stage for nodes without data packets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPL looks at the neighbor statistics module. There are multiple options how the module might

1. If you provide a custom definion of the `LINK_STATS_CONF_INIT_ETX(stats)` macro, it will be used to initialize ETX.
2. Otherwise `(ETX_INIT * ETX_DIVISOR)` is used as the default value. `ETX_INIT` is defined to be 2 by default. `ETX_DIVISOR` is just a Contiki-specific scaling factor to avoid floating-point arithmetic.

Nodes often receive packets from neighbors before they transmit packets. In that case, RSSI estimate is known, but ETX is not known. To initialize an initial estimate of ETX from RSSI, add this line to `project-conf.h`:

```
#define LINK_STATS_CONF_INIT_ETX(stats) guess_etx_from_rssi(stats)
```

In this way, nodes with strong signal will be preferred for routing in absence of other information. Look at `net/link-stats.c` for the details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. 
Anyway, in some research articles (such as Orchestra Sensys 2015, etc), the authors mentioned that RPL is designed mainly to support Upward Routing, so Link PRR (or PDR) of Upward routing is better than Downward one. However Downward routing uses reversed link of upward. 
How do you think about this problem ? and why is upward routing better than Downward ?

Comment: I have tried to do a lot of experiments in various scenarios to evaluate the performance of RPL Upward/Downward routing. And the results show that Downward is worse than Upward in terms of Average Link PRR and PDR. 
So I think the reason for this is that existing ETX calcualation is not support efficiently for Downward.

Comment: http://disi.unitn.it/~picco/papers/commag16.pdf this mentions one reason why downward routing is worse that is not related to ETX.